# Suite Commerce Advance 2016: Custom 'Item' Field Based--> 'Product Listing Page'

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

We have Suite Commerce Advance Vension Release Installed at our end, Which has good features 'Commerce Categories'. Our client don't want to use this category based structure.

They asked to design site based on attributes(custom item fields). So  we don't have any categories in the site. I wanted to know is it possible to get this done?

Example-->

Consider Men is one custom item field, so on product listing page we will only show products which are Men type along with its Facets/Sort fields.

How and where we need to make changes for get this done? Any help would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to create these as facets fields, then copy the link to your chosen facet into the SuiteCommerce Configuration record and create navigation link that way.

The SuiteCommerce Configuration record can be found by going to:
Setup > SuiteCommerce Advanced > Configuration.

Please ensure that you also have the bundle installed. It's provided by NetSuite and free with SCA Vinson